# getting form data with FormData()

Tags: javascript

I hope the week has seen you all well and you're all gearing up for a great weekend.  I've had to take up relearning of js and new learning of ajax recently and have a simple question I can't seem to resolve.

Take this sample form here ->

```
<form action="", method="post", onsubmit="return submitData(this)">
    First Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>

    Last Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"> <br>

    Age: <br>
    <input type="text" name="age"> <br>

    <input type="submit" id="buttonOne" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've been passing the morning familiarizing myself with XMLHttpRequest() and FormData() classes and have the following super simple snippets

```
function submitData(fdata) {
    var formData = new FormData(fdata);

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log( pair[0] + ' - ' + pair[1] );
    }   
}
```

AND

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key_1', 'First value');
formData.append('key_2', 'Second value');
formData.append('key_3', 'Third value');

for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log( pair[0] + ' - ' + pair[1] );
}
```

The bottom one, where I create the form data programatically displays the data in console properly. The top one where I try to pull the data from the form does not work. Could someone break down what is happening here and point out the errors in my thinking please. Thank you

Comment: Dont forget to add enctype='multipart/form-data' property to your form.

Comment: @ZrelliMajdi That's only needed if the form contains file inputs.

Comment: In the first one, when you submit the form the page reloads. Unless you've enabled the "Preserve log" option in the console, the console is cleared.

Comment: Check this documentation may help You. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Your first option should work if you've initialised `fdata` properly, but you don't show that.